# Array read method being called from main and having data entered and saved to array from another method causes error in run

Tags: java, arrays, global, local

so Im in uni and have been learning the logical pieces of java, for, do while, if, switch, etc. I have my project done for this Saturday and the issue is that I have created three classes, `Administrator` which has a `boot()` method (to enter quantity of users in the Array that will be initialized soon), the `Proyecto` which is where the main is, and the `Socios` class, where are the `createSocio(5 string vars)` and the `desplegarSocio()`//Reads the position in array and prints a console line of the data in the space.

Now I have trouble when I want to make it print the info because it doesn't prints anything. Down I have the code for each class.

Administrador.java

```
package proyecto;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Mo
 */
public class Administrador {
    public void Administrador(){
    }
    public static int cant;//cantidad users(dimension Array);

    public static void boot(){
        System.out.println("Por favor ingrese la cantidad de usuarios del sistema.");

        do{
         Scanner b= new Scanner(System.in);
         cant= b.nextInt();
         if(cant<1){System.out.println("Caracter no aceptado o numero inválido, por favor ingrese la cantidad.");}
        }while(cant<1);
    }
}
```

Socios.java

```
package proyecto;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Socios {

    public String[][] user = new String[Administrador.cant][4];
    public int c= Administrador.cant;

    public void Socios(){}
    public void crearSocio(){}
    public void consultarSocio(){}
    public static int contador=1;

    public void crearSocio(String nom, String ced, String fafi, String tmem){
        if(contador<=Administrador.cant){
            user[contador][0]= nom;//nombre
            user[contador][1]= ced;//cedula
            user[contador][2]= fafi;//fecha de afiliacion
            user[contador][3]= tmem;//tipo de membresia
            contador++;
        } else { 
            System.out.println("Base de datos llena.");
        }

        System.out.println("Su id de socio es: "+contador);
    }

    public void consultarSocio(int a){
        for(int b=0; b<4&&a>0&&a<Administrador.cant;){//b: identificador de nombre de dato;

            switch(b){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("El nombre es:");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("El numero de cedula es:");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("La fecha de afiliacion es:");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("El tipo de membresia es:");
                break;
            }

            System.out.print(user[a][b]);

            b++;
        }
    }
}
```

The main is this one:

```
package proyecto;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Mo
 */
public class Proyecto {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Variables
        Scanner opcion= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner socio= new Scanner(System.in);
        Socios identificador= new Socios();
        Scanner var1= new Scanner(System.in), var2 = new Scanner(System.in), var3= new Scanner(System.in), var4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, menu;
        String nsNombre, nsCedula, nsFAF, nsTMEM;

        System.out.println("Bienevenido a Sistema Administrativo del Club.");
        System.out.println("Cargando Sistema...");
        Administrador.boot();

        //boot sistema
        do{        
        System.out.println("Digite el numero de la opcion a elegir:");
        System.out.println("1. Consultar informacion de socio.");
        System.out.println("2. Crear nuevo socio.");
        System.out.println("3. Modificar socio existente.");
        System.out.println("4. Consultar reserva.");
        System.out.println("5. Realizar Reserva.");

        menu = opcion.nextInt();//Opcion(Integer) menu

            do{
            if(menu>6||menu<1){
                System.out.println("El dato ingresado no es valido.");
                System.out.println("Digite el numero de la opcion a elegir:");
                System.out.println("1. Consultar informacion de socio.");
                System.out.println("2. Crear nuevo socio.");
                System.out.println("3. Modificar socio existente.");
                System.out.println("4. Consultar reserva.");
                System.out.println("5. Realizar Reserva.");
                System.out.println("6.Salir.");
                 a=opcion.nextInt();
            }
        }while(menu<1||menu>6);

        switch(menu){
            case 1://Consultar info de Socio
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el numero de id del socio.");
                a = socio.nextInt();
                identificador.consultarSocio(a);
                break;
            case 2://Crean nuevo socio
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el Nombre completo.");
                nsNombre= var1.next();
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el numero de cedula.");
                nsCedula= var2.next();
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese la fecha de afiliacion.");
                nsFAF=var3.next();
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el tipo de membresia.");
                nsTMEM=var4.next();

                Socios test= new Socios();
                test.crearSocio(nsNombre, nsCedula, nsFAF, nsTMEM);


                break;
            case 3://Modificar socio
                break;
            case 4://Ver Reserva
                break;
            case 5://Reservar
                break;

            }    
        } while(menu!=6);

    }
}
```

Now the mistake in the console when i run and try to print the array, its just empty...

I thank you so much, I have tried to initialize the contador int variable not in 1 but 0 and viceverse, but it just breaks if i use the 0 as starting value or validating value. Im trying to do some sort of "database"-use array but idk if the global and local struggles with saving the data in the array and being the main reason why its not echoing anything on console.

Take in consideration I'm going through coding I course so I have not taken php clases or else, and we are being evaluated basic java so yh, not much libraries to choose from.

Comment: I'm going to guess it has something to do with the number of `Scanner`s you have. They all point to `System.in` and all you're doing is sequential reads with them, so you only need one.

Comment: I tried to use only 1, and the method wouldn't work so I just made 4.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code is riddled with traps, however for the sake of getting it "going"...

For my suggestions to work, you need to set contador to zero:

```
public static int contador=0;
```

Then, your user "database" needs to be static, and only initialised once you know how many users there are going to be:

```
public static String[][] user = null;
...
public void crearSocio(String nom, String ced, String fafi, String tmem){
        if(user==null){
            user = new String[Administrador.cant][4];
        }
        if(contador<=Administrador.cant){
            user[contador][0]= nom;//nombre
            user[contador][1]= ced;//cedula
            user[contador][2]= fafi;//fecha de afiliacion
            user[contador][3]= tmem;//tipo de membresia
            contador++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("databasis vol.");
        }

        System.out.println("vennoot id is: "+contador);
    }
```

Then, when you print, you need to modify your condition from:

```
for(; b<4&&a>0&&a<Administrador.cant;)
```

to

```
for(; b<4&&a>0&&a<=Administrador.cant;)
```

Comment: Alright gotcha, so I initialize it in crearSocio and not outside for it to be like global and defined? For the desplegarSocio it will be able to read the data saved in the array calling the data from this other method? I've struggled a bit with static and global and local variables performance and compatibility between these type of usage. Ty overall, appreciate it man✋

Comment: "Alright gotcha, so I initialize it in crearSocio and not outside for it to be like global and defined?" - Yes, since you determine the size of the Administrators at runtime. Also, It would be better if you used Collections though instead of arrays.